# How to run Python interpreter with arguments in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Specifically, I want to run `python`**`-m cProfile -o file`**`/.../ptsvd_launcher.py --... myScript.py`

Is there a launch configuration that can do that?

Comment: You could setup a [task](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks) for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating a [launch configuration](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging) with:

```
"module": "cProfile",
"args": ["-o", "file", <path>, "--", "myScript.py"]
```